# Windows 10, Settings -> Backup options, remove multiple (or all) folders at once

Tags: windows-10, backup

In the Backup of Windows 10, a lot of directories have been added by default. I can click one and then click "Remove", but doing so has a lot of delay and the entire page reloads itself (you have to scroll to the previous location again). Doing this 10+ times seems to be stupid. Is there any way to remove all at once?

I have tried to select multiple folders with Ctrl, but it did not work.

[image]A screenshot from [this page](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2974385/windows/how-to-use-windows-10s-file-history-backup-feature.html).

Comment: I found a [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1647784) with this answer. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 5):

Adding any folder to "exclude these folders" will also remove all subfolders under that folder from backup folder list. In your case,there are many subfolders like downloads, contacts, favourite etc which are under Users folder.So adding "Users" folder to "exclude these fodlers" will also move all subfolders to "exclude these folders" list.

Comment: A pretty shaky workaround: (1) Only works for the immediate sub-folders, not recursively (e.g., excluding "C:\" does not remove all the default folders, while excluding "C:\Users" does). (2) When removing the excluded folder from the exclusion list, the long original folder list reappears :(

Answer (score 0):

Include the C drive on EXCLUDE these folders. All the folders will get removed from the INCLUDE section. [SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ZRR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).