# How can I clear the "backup these folders" list in File History?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I want to use File History.

When I start the program and look at the backup options there is the section "backup these folders".
This list contains maybe 30 folder names on my PC. I don't want to backup most of them.
When I click on an entry and click then on "Remove" it takes a long time (maybe 30 seconds) before the entry is removed. Then I can remove the next entry, etc.

**I want to be able to remove many entries fast and don't remove one by one and wait and wait.**

**Is there a way to remove all folders which should be backed up with one command?**

Or is there a list (like an ini file) which I can edit to make this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this: https://itectec.com/superuser/configuring-windows-8-8-1-10-file-history-via-command-line/

Which states:

> configuration is stored in xml files in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`. It's referenced in registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\fhsvc\Parameters\Configs` with value name = path to configuration folder (as above), and value data = REG_DWORD:1.

> But simply adding these files and registry values and starting the service (there's script for it) does not start backups, neither configuration gets updated in Control Panel. However if File History is configured already, updates to xml files get reflected in control panel.

I had two `.xml` files in the above directory: `Config1.xml` & `Config2.xml` (seemingly identical on quick look at contents).

Per the O.P.'s comments, editing `Config1.xml` did the trick.

For those interested, the aritcle also has iformation regarding programtic manipulation via a COM object.